# Warning glmer: GLMM failed

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have to run a glmer with a continuous response variable, two variable as fixed effects and random effect:

```
       glmer.1 <- glmer(Conc ~ Metodo * Kit +
               (1|Especie),
             data = Input_2,
             family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

I got this warning message:

```
           Warning messages:
           1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
           Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0652105 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
           2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
           Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
            - Rescale variables?
```

I tried this with bobyqa() as optimization argument and got this warning messages:

```
           glmer.Conc<-glmer(Conc ~ Metodo * Kit 
              +  (1 | Especie),
              data = Input_2, 
              control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), 
              family = Gamma)

           Warning messages:
           1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
             Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0747655 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
           2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
             Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
            - Rescale variables?
```

my summary looks like this:

```
            summary(glmer.1)
            Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']                                                
             Family: Gamma  ( inverse )
            Formula: Conc ~ Metodo * Kit + (1 | Especie)
               Data: Input_2

                 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
              3202.0   3223.6  -1595.0   3190.0      264 

            Scaled residuals: 
                Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
            -0.7347 -0.5647 -0.2876  0.2740 12.0396 

            Random effects:
             Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
             Especie  (Intercept) 5.264e-05 0.007256
             Residual             1.724e+00 1.313030
            Number of obs: 270, groups:  Especie, 6

            Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)   
            (Intercept)  0.0089191  0.0028893   3.087  0.00202 **
            Metodo      -0.0002581  0.0009247  -0.279  0.78013   
            Kit         -0.0009974  0.0007818  -1.276  0.20203   
            Metodo:Kit   0.0007497  0.0004608   1.627  0.10380   
            ---
            Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

            Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                       (Intr) Metodo Kit   
            Metodo     -0.531              
            Kit        -0.531  0.857       
            Metodo:Kit  0.449 -0.907 -0.897
            convergence code: 0
            Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0652105 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
            Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
             - Rescale variables?
```

Especie represent the type of specie, the metodo and kit represent what type of method and kit was used to obtain the concentration and Conc is concentraction values

My data frame looks like this:

```
             Input_2 <- readr::read_table2("Especie Metodo  Kit Conc    A1  A2
                1   1   1   70.4    1.5 0.9
                1   1   1   57.2    1.7 1.4
                1   1   1   22.2    1.6 1.1
                1   1   1   60.6    1.5 0.9
                1   1   1   50.2    1.6 1
                1   1   2   40.5    2.1 1.7
                1   1   2   86.6    2.1 2.1
                1   1   2   53.9    1.8 1.3
                1   1   2   50.3    1.9 0.2
                1   1   2   44.1    2   1.5
                1   1   3   159.1   2.1 2.3
                1   1   3   246 2.1 2.4
                1   1   3   81.5    2   1.3
                1   1   3   107.9   2.1 1.9
                1   1   3   125 2   1.7
                1   2   1   72.9    1.6 1.1
                1   2   1   38.1    1.6 1.1
                1   2   1   8.3 1.3 1.8
                1   2   1   31  1.6 0.8
                1   2   1   36.3    1.3 1.2
                1   2   2   16.8    1.9 1.8
                1   2   2   4.8 2.2 1
                1   2   2   20.4    1.4 1
                1   2   2   31.8    1.9 0.4
                1   2   2   5   1.6 1
                1   2   3   17.9    2   2.2
                1   2   3   14.9    2.6 2.5
                1   2   3   5.3 1.6 0.5
                1   2   3   17.1    2.2 1.3
                1   2   3   17.1    1.9 1
                1   3   1   67.3    1.6 1
                1   3   1   11.3    1.4 0.7
                1   3   1   4.2 1   1
                1   3   1   9.7 1.1 0.8
                1   3   1   20  1.4 0.8
                1   3   2   4.3 1.4 1.3
                1   3   2   4.1 1.6 2
                1   3   2   11.4    1.5 0.3
                1   3   2   12.5    1.4 0.2
                1   3   2   11  1.5 0.9
                1   3   3   59.7    1.9 2.4
                1   3   3   81.4    2.3 2.4
                1   3   3   32.2    1.9 1.6
                1   3   3   24.9    1.8 1.2
                1   3   3   50.9    2.1 1.2
                2   1   1   185 1.6 1
                2   1   1   146.2   1.7 1.2
                2   1   1   239 1.8 1.4
                2   1   1   141.9   2   2
                2   1   1   303.7   1.9 1.8
                2   1   2   53.6    1.9 0.6
                2   1   2   424.8   2.1 1.5
                2   1   2   30.3    1.9 0.4
                2   1   2   291 2.1 1.5
                2   1   2   471.6   2.1 2.1
                2   1   3   132.8   1.9 1.4
                2   1   3   124.5   2.1 1.7
                2   1   3   484.4   2.1 2.1
                2   1   3   251.3   2.2 2.2
                2   1   3   598.6   2.1 2.2
                2   2   1   15.6    1.4 0.9
                2   2   1   107.6   1.7 1.1
                2   2   1   172.2   1.8 1.6
                2   2   1   210.2   1.9 1.9
                2   2   1   699.7   2   2.2
                2   2   2   20  1.7 0.2
                2   2   2   86.2    2   0.9
                2   2   2   36.8    2.1 0.3
                2   2   2   434.4   2.1 2.3
                2   2   2   209.5   2.2 1.5
                2   2   3   37  2.1 1.6
                2   2   3   94.8    2.1 1.8
                2   2   3   220.2   2.2 2.1
                2   2   3   17.7    2.3 0.8
                2   2   3   145.3   2.1 1.9
                2   3   1   33.4    1.5 0.8
                2   3   1   87  1.7 1.2
                2   3   1   98.9    1.8 1.8
                2   3   1   176.6   2   2.2
                2   3   1   180.7   1.9 1.9
                2   3   2   20.8    1.8 0.3
                2   3   2   226.2   2.1 1.1
                2   3   2   227.8   2.1 1.7
                2   3   2   40.8    2.1 0.4
                2   3   2   83.4    2.1 0.9
                2   3   3   35.7    2.1 1.2
                2   3   3   191.9   2.1 1.8
                2   3   3   203.2   2.2 2.2
                2   3   3   143.3   2.2 2
                2   3   3   70.7    2.1 1.7
                3   1   1   190.7   2.1 2
                3   1   1   456.5   2   2.2
                3   1   1   520.9   2   2.2
                3   1   1   535.5   2   2.1
                3   1   1   894.3   2   2.3
                3   1   2   265.2   2.1 1.7
                3   1   2   392.2   2.1 2.3
                3   1   2   241.3   2.1 1.4
                3   1   2   156.9   2.1 1.7
                3   1   2   277.2   2.1 1.7
                3   1   3   431.6   2.1 2.1
                3   1   3   669.9   2.2 2.3
                3   1   3   342.5   2.1 2.1
                3   1   3   572.3   2.1 2.2
                3   1   3   435.2   2.1 2.1
                3   2   1   498.6   2   2.1
                3   2   1   1137.2  2.1 2.3
                3   2   1   764.5   2.1 2.3
                3   2   1   746.4   2.1 2.2
                3   2   1   737.2   2.1 2.2
                3   2   2   98.1    2   1.4
                3   2   2   237.9   2.1 2.2
                3   2   2   144 2   1.2
                3   2   2   240.3   2.1 2.1
                3   2   2   253.4   2.1 1.8
                3   2   3   247.3   2.2 1.7
                3   2   3   155.3   2.1 1.8
                3   2   3   179.3   2.2 1.6
                3   2   3   225.7   2.1 2.2
                3   2   3   274.4   2.1 2.1
                3   3   1   944.9   2.1 2.3
                3   3   1   978.4   2.1 2.3
                3   3   1   785.9   2   2.1
                3   3   1   510.7   2   2.1
                3   3   1   164.5   2   2.2
                3   3   2   48.1    2   0.3
                3   3   2   427.7   2.1 2.2
                3   3   2   75  2   0.9
                3   3   2   153 2.1 1.3
                3   3   2   293.8   2.1 2.4
                3   3   3   335.8   2.1 1.9
                3   3   3   395.5   2.1 2.1
                3   3   3   181.1   2.1 1.9
                3   3   3   468.4   2.1 2.2
                3   3   3   348 2.1 2.1
                4   1   1   335.8   2   1.9
                4   1   1   188.1   1.9 1.5
                4   1   1   219 2   2
                4   1   1   104.1   1.9 1.3
                4   1   1   273.7   2   2
                4   1   2   573.2   2.2 1.8
                4   1   2   115.3   2.1 2.1
                4   1   2   56.7    2   0.4
                4   1   2   316.5   2.1 1.6
                4   1   2   85.2    2.1 1.9
                4   1   3   585 2.2 2.3
                4   1   3   377.5   2.1 2
                4   1   3   47.1    2.1 1.6
                4   1   3   73.1    2   1.4
                4   1   3   91.9    2   1.2
                4   2   1   374.8   2   1.7
                4   2   1   85.8    1.9 1.9
                4   2   1   53.1    1.8 1.8
                4   2   1   34.3    1.8 1.1
                4   2   1   27  1.9 1.1
                4   2   2   182.9   2.1 1.3
                4   2   2   25.3    1.8 0.4
                4   2   2   4.4 2.4 0.1
                4   2   2   117.8   2.2 2.1
                4   2   2   6.6 1.9 0.8
                4   2   3   158.9   2.2 2.2
                4   2   3   44.5    2   1
                4   2   3   12.6    1.7 0.5
                4   2   3   22.5    2.3 1
                4   2   3   91  2   1.3
                4   3   1   212.1   1.7 1.2
                4   3   1   101.7   1.9 1.8
                4   3   1   63.4    1.4 0.9
                4   3   1   67.9    1.8 1.3
                4   3   1   40.4    1.6 0.9
                4   3   2   73  2.1 0.9
                4   3   2   33.1    2.1 0.6
                4   3   2   7.8 2   0.3
                4   3   2   10.9    1.9 1.4
                4   3   2   11.6    2   0.2
                4   3   3   382.8   2.2 2.3
                4   3   3   7   2.4 0.4
                4   3   3   13.1    2   0.7
                4   3   3   24.7    2.2 1.1
                4   3   3   42.9    2   0.9
                5   1   1   340 1.4 0.9
                5   1   1   48.6    1.5 0.6
                5   1   1   53.7    1.4 0.6
                5   1   1   33.3    1.3 0.5
                5   1   1   86  1.3 0.5
                5   1   2   11.4    1.4 0.5
                5   1   2   27  1.6 1
                5   1   2   33.7    1.7 0.9
                5   1   2   14.2    1.8 1.3
                5   1   2   16.2    1.9 0.8
                5   1   3   606 1.6 0.7
                5   1   3   265.8   1.7 1
                5   1   3   73.5    1.5 2.6
                5   1   3   189 1.6 0.7
                5   1   3   223.1   1.6 0.7
                5   2   1   101.5   1.5 0.6
                5   2   1   7.2 1.2 0.5
                5   2   1   49.7    1.4 0.7
                5   2   1   61.9    1.5 0.6
                5   2   1   6.9 1.1 0.6
                5   2   2   20.6    1.4 0.7
                5   2   2   13.7    1.7 1
                5   2   2   48.5    1.8 1
                5   2   2   6.8 1.6 0.7
                5   2   2   5.7 1.3 0.7
                5   2   3   239.5   1.7 0.8
                5   2   3   152.5   1.7 0.8
                5   2   3   2065.4  1.5 1
                5   2   3   112.7   1.6 0.6
                5   2   3   104.5   1.6 0.7
                5   3   1   40.7    1.3 0.5
                5   3   1   82  1.4 0.9
                5   3   1   20.6    1.3 1
                5   3   1   21.4    1.4 0.6
                5   3   1   29.6    1.4 0.6
                5   3   2   4.3 1.1 0.5
                5   3   2   38.5    1.3 1.3
                5   3   2   22.9    1.7 1.1
                5   3   2   10.3    1.7 1
                5   3   2   4.9 1.3 0.6
                5   3   3   216.8   1.7 0.8
                5   3   3   220.7   1.7 0.9
                5   3   3   51.8    1.3 1.3
                5   3   3   161 1.6 0.7
                5   3   3   144.4   1.6 0.6
                6   1   1   79.9    2.1 1.8
                6   1   1   295.3   2.1 2.1
                6   1   1   136.4   2.1 2.1
                6   1   1   177.3   2   2.1
                6   1   1   116.4   1.7 1.1
                6   1   2   93.1    2.1 2.2
                6   1   2   385.9   2.1 2.3
                6   1   2   318.6   2.1 1.8
                6   1   2   20.3    2.1 1.4
                6   1   2   131.5   2.1 1.4
                6   1   3   53.9    2.2 2.7
                6   1   3   156.9   2.2 1.8
                6   1   3   344.7   2.1 2
                6   1   3   15.5    2.6 0.6
                6   1   3   33.7    2.1 1.3
                6   2   1   137.8   1.8 1.2
                6   2   1   104 2.1 2
                6   2   1   151.7   2.1 2
                6   2   1   15.4    2.1 1.6
                6   2   1   31.5    1.9 2.1
                6   2   2   8   2.1 1.5
                6   2   2   23.9    2   0.9
                6   2   2   14.8    2.2 0.4
                6   2   2   8.6 1.8 0.4
                6   2   2   18.2    2.2 0.3
                6   2   3   35  2.2 2.7
                6   2   3   61  2.2 1.7
                6   2   3   136.9   2.1 2.3
                6   2   3   3.1 8.5 0.2
                6   2   3   8.7 1.6 1.1
                6   3   1   155.7   2   2.2
                6   3   1   48.5    1.7 0.9
                6   3   1   77.7    2   1.5
                6   3   1   45.6    1.6 1.2
                6   3   1   142 1.6 1.1
                6   3   2   5.6 1.4 1.3
                6   3   2   7.4 2.2 0.1
                6   3   2   66.4    1.9 1.4
                6   3   2   6.8 2.3 0.7
                6   3   2   10.3    1.9 2.2
                6   3   3   42.9    2.1 2.5
                6   3   3   48.3    2.3 1.2
                6   3   3   62.6    2.3 1.4
                6   3   3   6.9 2.2 0.3
                6   3   3   3.9 1.8 0.5")
```

Did I forget anything to include to the GLMM? Thanks!

Edit 1:

I have converted the Method and Kit variables to factor formats:

```
           Input_2$Metodo<-as.factor(Input_2$Metodo)

           Input_2$Kit<-as.factor(Input_2$Kit)
```

Obtaining a different warming:

```
               Warning messages:
               1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
               Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00649539 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
               2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
                Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
                - Rescale variables?
```

How can I solve these problems?

Based on suggestion, I have tried to reescale my values:

```
            numcols <- grep("^c\\.",names(Input_2))
            dfs <- Input_2
            dfs[,numcols] <- scale(dfs[,numcols])
            m1_sc <- update(glmer.1,data=dfs)

           Obtaining the next warming message:

           Warning messages:
           1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
           Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00649539 (tol = 0.002, component                1)
           2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
             Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
            - Rescale variables?
```

Edit2: based on the suggestions I have removed my interaction * for + in addition I have converted the species column into a factor:

```
           Input_2$Especie<-as.factor(Input_2$Especie)

           glmer.1 <- glmer(Conc ~ Metodo + Kit +
                              (1|Especie),
                            data = Input_2,
                            family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

and I get the next warming:

```
         Warning messages:
         1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
           Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00513611 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
         2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
           Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
          - Rescale variables?
```

A second suggestion was to change the glmer to glm to see if the model was saturated with a simpler strategy (as the glm requires all factors to be fixed I changed the species variable to fixed factor):

```
                   glmer.1 <- glm(Conc ~ Metodo + Kit +Especie,
                                             data = Input_2,
                                             family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

And when I execute it, I have no problem.

How can I solve these problems with the glmer?What is my mistake?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The warning messages suggest rescaling your variables -- have you tried that?In particular, you could try converting your ```Conc``` values into z-scores.

Comment: Thank you @Izzy for your answer. I have not try it. How can I do that? Why intro z-score? Why I must rescaling my variables? It should be enought without reescaling strategy?

Comment: Although you are using ```glmer``` and not ```lme4```, check out this [link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html) for some description about this issue and other convergence problems -- it's many of the same types of issues. Basically, sometimes large differences in variables can result in numerical problems, which can make it difficult to converge. Centering and scaling your continuous variables (i.e. through z-scoring) can help address this problem. There are some other suggestions in that link too.